# Best Practices: Web Cartography Design

Tags: maps, reports, case-studies

I am looking for ANY studies completed on mapping solutions for the web or interactive devices. Specifically related to:

- Optimum View Window Size
- Control Paradigms (Zoom/Markers)
- Visual Design of Map Components (Color Contrast / Typography / Iconography)

What are some of the top studies or resources available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a bit of research on cartography on the web, but most of it is not recent. [The Commission on Maps and The Internet](http://maps.unomaha.edu/ica/Default.html) has published two books on the topic.

While I haven't used the material personally, it might be of some use to you.

Comment: A [google scholar search](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&q=maps+on+the+internet&btnG=) should help you, if you haven't had a look at it already.